# Unity C# Levels menu, problem with locked/unlocked levels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, menu, game-development, levels

I have this PlayerPrefsUpdate.cs for my levels menu:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerPrefsUpdate : MonoBehaviour {

   public int PlayerLevel = 0;

    private int LastLevel = -1;

    private void Start() {
        PlayerLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PlayerLevel");
    }

    private void Update() {
        if (LastLevel != PlayerLevel) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerLevel", PlayerLevel);
            LastLevel = PlayerLevel;
        }
    }
}
```

If i play for example 4 levels, 5 levels are unlocked and everything is fine.

[image: unlocked]

But if i play again the level 1, the levels are locked again. How can i do ?

[image: locked]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking if the last level you've played is not the `PlayerLevel` check that it is greater instead.

```cs
        if (LastLevel > PlayerLevel) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerLevel", PlayerLevel);
            LastLevel = PlayerLevel;
        }
```

The naming you have is a bit confusing, so it might be the other way around. But you want to check if the level you just played is greater than the biggest you've played so far. Furthermore, you really should not need to have this inside the `Update` function as I would expect it would not change before completing a new level and returning to the menu screen.

If the problem is that that the PlayerPrefs' `PlayerLevel` variable is the only thing you persists, you might want to check that you are increasing it when you update it:

```cs
int progressedToLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PlayerLevel");
if (currentLevel > progressedToLevel) {
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerLevel", currentLevel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I succeded with this code in GameManager.cs :

```
public void CompleteLevel ()
 {
      int savedPlayerLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PlayerLevel");
      int newPlayerLevel = Mathf.Max(PlayerLevel, savedPlayerLevel);
      PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerLevel", newPlayerLevel);
      completeLevelUI.SetActive(true);
  }
```